# How to get Cuda to use gcc 4.6

Tags: gcc, cuda

I am trying to install Cuda on my machine and as usual it causes problem with gcc 4.7 when trying to run the installer.

I have now installed gcc 4-6 which should work and I am now thinking about the best way to install CUDA.

I have thought about creating a symlink to gcc-4.6 so that the installer uses version 4.6 instead of 4.7.

Do you have any suggestions to do that or is there a better solution? It feels a bit stupid erase 4.7 from the machine in order to use cuda.

Thanks in advance!
/ Erik

Comment: possible duplicate of [CUDA and gcc compatibility issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14787148/cuda-and-gcc-compatibility-issue)

Comment: No, that guy is trying to compile a program he has written, I can't install cuda on my computer.

Comment: Of course it should be possible to delete gcc 4.7 and only work with 4.6, but I want to find a better solution.

Comment: And I can't do sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.6 /usr/local/cuda/bin/gcc because the bin directory has not yet been created.

Comment: You can use gcc 4.7 (or even 4.8) to install CUDA and compile CUDA programs. Some patches have to be applied for it to work. You can check the [Arch Linux CUDA install script](https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/community.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/cuda) to see the kind of operations that need to be applied.

Comment: You can force-install the toolkit.  To do this, take the cuda 5 installer and then extract the individual installers.  Use the `--help` command line switch with the installer to learn how to do this.  Once you have the individual installers (driver, toolkit, samples) extracted, you can run the toolkit installer manually and it will install the cuda 5 toolkit.  Finally you can fixup your host compiler path using any of several methods.  One method is to use the `--compiler-bindir` option with [nvcc](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#file-and-path-specifications).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create alternatives so that you can switch between versions at any time check out this helpful page:

[How to change the default GCC compiler in Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832892/how-to-change-the-default-gcc-compiler-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution to your problem is to download CUDA 5.5, which works with gcc 4.7. It is currently only available to CUDA registered developers: [link to forum announcement](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/545506/new-cuda-5-5-release-candidate-now-available-for-cuda-registered-developers/)